# Change color of a sample pixels in contact with a determinated color - python

Tags: python, image, colors, python-imaging-library, pixel

I have this image:

[image]

And I would like to change the group with white pixels just in contact with the black pixels by red pixels. It's possible to replace especific colors by another using this code:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open('fig1.png')
data = np.array(im)

r1, g1, b1 = 255, 255, 255 # Original value
r2, g2, b2 = 0, 0, 0 # Value that we want to replace it with

red, green, blue = data[:,:,0], data[:,:,1], data[:,:,2]
mask = (red == r1) & (green == g1) & (blue == b1)
data[:,:,:3][mask] = [r2, g2, b2]

im = Image.fromarray(data)
```

Is it possible to replace a sample of white pixels for red pixels, but just the white pixels in contact with black pixels?

Comment: You seem to have posted a lossy JPEG image with 3855 colours which is really not ideal if that is supposed to be a 3-colour segmentation. Do you have a proper PNG please?

Comment: Also it is not 100% clear what you mean by *"only white pixels touching black ones"*. What happens if there is a 4-pixel thick layer of white pixels between black and red pixels? Do all 4 pixels get changed to black or just the outermost layer where they touch black?

Comment: Actually, I made a mistake, I updated my question. And yes just the outermost layer where they touch black. And I would like to replace white pixels for red pixels, and not white for black, my bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

I am still not 100% certain what you want, but this should give you a good basis for doing what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from skimage.morphology import dilation

# Load image - and make into Numpy array
# It is a palette image. 0=black, 1=white, 2=red
im = Image.open('start.png')
na = np.array(im)

# Make mask of white pixels - True where white
whiteMask = na==1
Image.fromarray((whiteMask*255).astype(np.uint8)).save('DEBUG-whiteMask.png')

# Make mask of black pixels - True where black
blackMask = na==0
Image.fromarray((blackMask*255).astype(np.uint8)).save('DEBUG-blackMask.png')

# Footprint of structuring element for morphology
# Unused at the moment:
# footprint = np.zeros((3, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
# footprint[1, 1] = 1

# Do the morphology on blackMask
touchingBlack = dilation(blackMask, footprint=None)

# Now find pixels that are both white and touching black
resultMask = np.logical_and(whiteMask, touchingBlack)
Image.fromarray((resultMask*255).astype(np.uint8)).save('DEBUG-resultMask.png')

# Make those pixels red
na[resultMask] = 2

# Convert back into PIL Image and reinstate original palette
res = Image.fromarray(na)
res.putpalette(im.getpalette())
res.save('result.png')
```

It uses my *"corrected"* starting image from below, and produces this:

[image]

**Original Answer**

I'll update this answer if/when you provide a decent lossless PNG input image and clarify what you mean by *"pixels touching black"*.

For the moment, I have *"corrected"* your image to just three colours:

[image]

and tried my algorithm with **ImageMagick** in the Terminal for expedience until we are sure what the aim is.

```
# Find white pixels
magick start.png -fill black +opaque white white.png
```

[image]

```
# Find black pixels
magick start.png -fill white +opaque black -negate black.png
```

[image]

```
# Find pixels touching black pixels
magick black.png -morphology dilate square:1 black-d.png
```

[image]

```
# Find black pixels that are both white and touching black
magick white.png black-d.png -compose darken -composite result.png
```

[image]

---

I *"corrected"* the original image, which was a lossy JPEG into a 3-colour PNG as follows...

First, I made a swatch of the 3 pure colours I wanted to remap the image to. I did that with **ImageMagick** as follows:

```
magick xc:red xc:black xc:white +append swatch.png
```

That makes a tiny 3x1 image with 1 red, 1 black and 1 white pixel. Then I remapped the original image to those 3 colours with **ImageMagick** using:

```
magick original.jpg +dither -remap swatch.png start.png
```

Then I hand-edited 6-8 stray pixels.

Comment: So sorry, I made some mistakes, considere you're last image, there are a 'white board', I would like to replace these white pixels for red pixels, but on original image. Did you understand? Thanks for your time, and sorry for my confusion.

Comment: Perfect, another question, if possible. How  do you "corrected" my image with just three colours? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I'll add a bit into the bottom of my answer to explain that.

Comment: I have added in the *"correction"* procedure. Ideally, you would not need that and you would save your 3-colour segmented image as a lossless PNG rather than a lossy JPEG which is allowed to alter your pixels.

Comment: Sorry, again, and how would I change all white pixels between red and black color?

Comment: Do you mean you want all white pixels to become red? Or all white to become black?

Comment: Wold be red.... =)

Comment: Change this line `na[resultMask] = 2` to this `na[whiteMask] = 2`